# Backbone.js model.has method does not work on sub-objects

Tags: backbone.js

I am developing applications with backbone.js and I sometime use JSON based models containing sub-objects, like this one :

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3": {
         "key1": "value1"
        },

}
```

Now it seems that the model's method "has" (returning a boolean wether or not a key is part of the model) is not working for sub-objects.

For example, for the data above, this will return undefined

```
myModel.has("key3.key1")
```

Any idea how to treat this case?

Thanks

Comment: This should work.  And either way it should return false if the key is not present.  Is it possible your model is undefined?

Comment: That model would have a `'key3'`, not a `'key3.key1'`. There is no special support for nested properties like that.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot we built in custom support for dot notation in nested objects.  We do this by overwriting the get and set methods to split the field based on the `.`  Since `has` just calls `get` and checks for `!= null` you only need to fix the get method to make has work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, instead of overriding default behaviours, one can easily build this functionality with something similar to

```
var buildDeepMap = function(baseKey, map, obj){
    _.each(obj, function(value, objKey){
        var key = baseKey === ''? objKey : baseKey+'.'+objKey;
        if(typeof value === 'object'){
            buildDeepMap(key, map, value)
        }else{
            map[key]=value;
        }
    })
    return map;
}

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    constructor: function(){
        Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
        this.buildDeepMap();
    },
    buildDeepMap: function(){
        this.deepFlatIndex = buildDeepMap('', {}, this.toJSON());
    },
    deepHas: function(key){
        return _.has(this.deepFlatIndex, key)
    }
});
```

usage can be like this

```
 var data = {
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "value2",
     "key3": {
         "key1": "value1"
     }
 }
 var myDeepHasModel = new MyModel(data);

 console.log(myDeepHasModel.deepHas('key1')); //true
 console.log(myDeepHasModel.deepHas('key3.key1')); //true
 console.log(myDeepHasModel.deepHas('key3.key2')); //false
```